# Modify string using Unix CLI in all scss files

Tags: unix, sed, command-line-interface

I would like to get rid of all `@include rem()` statements in my sass files and I want to replace them for specified declarations and values, examples:

`@include rem(font-size, 11px);` has to be `font-size: 11px;` instead

`@include rem(height, 200px);` has to be `height: 200px;` and so on ...

Is it possible to replace it via Unix CLI (sed maybe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sass' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/@include rem(\([^,]\{1,\}\), *\([^)]\{1,\}\))/\1: \2/g'
```

If you are working on MacOS, please try instead:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sass' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '' 's/@include rem(\([^,]\{1,\}\), *\([^)]\{1,\}\))/\1: \2/g'
```

Comment: It prints error `sed: 1: "./test.scss": invalid command code .`, (I got MacOS)

Comment: I've updated my answer. How about now? (Not tested.)